# Variables for predicates in metagol

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, yap

The following program noMetagolR is given in:

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~shm/Papers/metagol_gram.pdf page 33.

```
parse(S,G1,G2) :- parse(s(0),S,[],G1,G2).

parse(Q,X,X,G1,G2) :- abduce(acceptor(Q),G1,G2).
parse(Q,[C|X],Y,G1,G2) :- Skolem(P), abduce(delta1(Q,C,P),G1,G3), parse(P,X,Y,G3,G2).

abduce(X,G,G) :- member(X,G).
abduce(X,G,[X|G]) :- not(member(X,G)).

Skolem(s(0)). Skolem(s(1)). ...
```

An example query is :

```
parse([],[],G1), parse([0],G1,G2), parse([0,0],G2,G3), parse([1,1],G3,G4), parse([0,0,0],G4,G5), parse([0,1,1],G5,G6), parse([1,0,1],G6,G),not(parse([1],G,G)), not(parse([0,1],G,G)).
```

The answer substitutions should return a learnt grammar for parity.

The program is said to run in Yap. I normally use SWI-prolog. Either way,
what do I do to make them understand `Skolem/1` ? Presumbly this means that `Skolem` is a variable? I thought maybe using `=..` but this does not work.

Also how many `Skolem/1` facts are needed?

Comment: A goal `Skolem(X)` may mean two different things: Either it means `'Skolem'(X)`, or it means `call(Skolem,X)`. So this may increase confusion, if you continue to use that syntax. Rather write `skolem(X)` instead.

Comment: When I have seen it before, I always interpreted it as 'call(Skolem,X).' But I have not seen facts of `Skolem/1` before so I didn't understand what they were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SWI-Prolog, you can place in your source the directive

```
:- set_prolog_flag(allow_variable_name_as_functor,true).
```

see [current_prolog_flag](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2)/2

example on REPL:

```
1 ?- set_prolog_flag(allow_variable_name_as_functor,true).
true.

2 ?- assert(X(1)).
true.

3 ?- X(Y).
Y = 1.
```

Comment: Any one know how to do this in yap?

Comment: to be true, I would with a simple edit/replace all Skolem with skolem, instead of set_prolog_flag(...). Just, skolem should be not already used...

Comment: Do you know why they might have used Skolem rather than skolem then? What is the point of this way of doing it?

Comment: It's not easy to answer. Since Skolemization it's at the core of the tech, I think they preferred to enforce the document layout and consistency, rather than worring about such a low level syntactic detail. Indeed, the document looks very interesting, but it seems to require proficiency in Prolog and ASP as well...

Comment: Well they have one implementation in prolog and one in asp, so I am just looking at the prolog one to begin with :)